# Double Spherical Pendulum Simulation in Java

Tags: java, processing, physics

I've been struggling with a personal project that I've been working on and I was wondering if I could have a bit of help.

basically what I'm trying to do is to simulate the movement of a double spherical pendulum using the Runge-Kutta method. If anyone does't know a double spherical pendulum it should look something like this: [Simulation using that doesn't use the Runge-Kutta method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN2eC.gif) Here is my post on the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Massive shoutout to @MassDefect who gave a super clear description.

So I used [Processing](http://processing.org) as my chosen distro because I saw the Coding Train's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWzPe_S-RVE) which I thought was really cool and I wanted to challenge myself. I basically followed the same syntax but for 3D so it's pretty simple. My issue is that the program crashes after 3 frames, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me?

Here is my program, sorry for the lack of equations, it was too long, i can send if anyone needs them:

```
import peasy.PeasyCam; // Camera for movement (variable for camera is cam)
PeasyCam cam;

// variables for maths
float l1 = 250;
float l2 = 250;
float m1 = 25;
float m2 = 25;
//angles
float theta1 = PI/16;
float phi1 = PI/4;
float theta2 = PI/4;
float phi2 = PI/24;
//velocities
float theta1d = 0;
float phi1d = 0;
float theta2d = 0;
float phi2d = 0;
//accelerations
float theta1dd = 0;
float phi1dd = 0;
float theta2dd = 0;
float phi2dd = 0;
//storage for new angles
//float newtheta1 = 0;
//float newphi1 = 0;
//float newtheta2 = 0;
//float newphi2 = 0;
float g = 9.807;
float i;





void settings(){
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  //smooth();
}

void setup() {
  cam = new PeasyCam(this,2000); // camera 2000 pixels away from origin along
  //camera(0,0,500, 0,0,0,-1,-1,-1);


}


void draw(){ 
  scale(1,-1,1); //I like the cartesian plane more
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  
  
  // A  X   I   S

  //Y - RED
  stroke(255,0,0);
  line(0,0,0,0,500,0);
  stroke(150,0,0);
  line(0,0,0,0,-500,0);
  

  
  //X - GREEN
  stroke(0,255,0);
  line(0,0,0,500,0,0);
  stroke(0,150,0);
  line(0,0,0,-500,0,0);
  
  //Z - BLUE
  stroke(0,0,255);
  line(0,0,0,0,0,500);
  stroke(0,0, 150);
  line(0,0,0,0,0,-500);
  
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
     
  cam.setYawRotationMode();  // Permit pich/roll only.
  
  //CHANGING THE VALUE 
  //theta  = t * w0   +   t^2 * 0.5 * angular acceleration
  //t = 1 frame its simplified to w0 + 0.5 * angular acceleration   

  // HUD for viewing data  
  cam.beginHUD();
  //debug printing
  textSize(25);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  text("theta1dd =" + theta1dd, 10, 85);
  text("phi1dd   =" + phi1dd, 10, 115);
  text("theta2dd =" + theta2dd, 10, 145);
  text("phi2dd   =" + phi2dd, 10, 175);   
  cam.endHUD();


  //finds the xyzzy values of the 2 "bobs"
  float x1 = l1*sin(theta1)*cos(phi1);
  float z1 = l1*sin(theta1)*sin(phi1);
  float y1 = -l1*cos(theta1);
  float x2 = x1 + l2*sin(theta2)*cos(phi2);
  float z2 = z1 + l2*sin(theta2)*sin(phi2);    
  float y2 = y1 - l2 * cos(theta2);
  
  


  phi1dd    = //long equation didn't fit in the post so ill make a comment
  phi2dd    =
  theta1dd  =
  theta2dd  =    

      // STORE new theta in new variable. 
    
      theta1   = theta1d + 0.5 * theta1dd;
     
      phi1     = phi1d + 0.5 * phi1dd;
      
      theta2   = theta2d + 0.5*theta2dd;
      
      phi2     = phi2d + 0.5*phi2dd;
     
     
      // FIND NEXT X, Z 
      //use the new value of theta for y, shouldn't matter
      //float x1 = l1*cos(theta1)*cos(phi1)*newtheta1 - l1*sin(theta1)*sin(phi1)*newphi1;
      //float x2 = x1 + l2*cos(theta2)*cos(phi2)*newtheta2 - l2*sin(theta2)*sin(phi2)*newphi2;
      //float z1 = l1*cos(theta1)*sin(phi1)*newtheta1 + l1*sin(theta1)*cos(phi1)*newphi1;
      //float z2 = z1 + l2*cos(theta2)*sin(phi2)*newtheta2 + l2*sin(theta2)*cos(phi2)*newphi2;
      //float y1 = l1*cos(newtheta1);
      //float y2 = y1 + l2*cos(newtheta2);
      
      //theta1 = newtheta1;
      //phi1 = newphi1;
      //theta2 = newtheta2;
      //phi2 = newphi2;
      
      
      
      //DRAW THE LINES/SPHERES
      //first pendulum
      line(0,0,0,x1,y1,z1);    
      fill(255);
      translate(x1, y1, z1);
      sphere(m1);
      translate(-x1,-y1,-z1);
      
      //second pendulum
      line(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2);
      fill(255);
      translate(x2,y2,z2);
      sphere(m2);
      translate(-x2,-y2,-z2);
      
      }
      delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: How does it crash, do you get an error & traceback?

Comment: Some of the values become exponential and then becomes NaN. It may be an issue with the maths.